# How "üçün" is Turkic but "çün" is Iranic?

Tags: etymology, turkish, turkic-languages

Azerbaijani: **çün**
Persian: çun
Means: because
Origin: Persian

Azerbaijani: **üçün** *üç+ün*
old-Turkic: uçun
Means: because of
Origin: old-Turkic

So, can somebody explain how this is possible?

More Explain:

It is not possible that **üçün** has been made using üç+ün
We don't have ün/un suffix in Turkic.
I think it was like "O çun" means "because of that" and cause of accent transformed to "üçün", cause you know in Turkic we can't have O and Ü together in one word.

Comment: Does this relate to Arabic [عشان](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%86#Egyptian_Arabic) (ʿašān), analyzed as from šaʾn "mater, sake, etc", with plural šuʾūn? For gods sakes, if it says Persian and Old-Turkic, that could mean somewhen between 1000 and 2000 years ago, which leaves a lot of room, and if Turkic doesn't have *ün*, that does not say much at all about Old Turkic. By the way, what's üç then? Does that relate to the question, that was posted here some moons ago, whether Turkish defies the maximal coda principle?

Comment: üç means 3 in Turkic.

Comment: also, it is not related to the Arabic one.

Comment: What I dislike more than you dislike Persian etymologies are the Arabic etymologies, where the roots rather serve to help remembering their system of conjugation and inflection, that is intensely complex from my point of view.

Comment: I meant, what I said were Arabic is actually cited as Egyptian Arabic. Not sure what difference it makes. Still not sure where it's from.

Comment: I think you should ask your question in a specialized forum with competent specialists of Turkic languages.

Comment: @ArnaudFournet Where for example? I only know here. also if you ask a Turkic professor about these words, +90% they will say they are Turkic.

Comment: @vectory Etymology in Arabic is a bit different from other languages, it is hard in Arabic to figure out a word is a loanword, for example, word قلعه is not Arabic, some people say it is from Turkic root Qalmaq which means "to stay", some people go and find a random Iranic word and claim it as Persian, lol

Comment: @ArnaudFournet. Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Turkic üçün is a postposition meaning “because of, on account of”. It is undeniably Turkic; see Clauson, Etym. dictionary of pre-13th-century Turkish, p. 28 seq.

Persian čūn is a conjunction meaning “when, since” and a preposition meaning “like, as”. It has an impeccable Iranian etymology:  Old Iranian či-gauna “what colour” > Middle Persian čiyōn > New Persian čūn.

The superficial similarity of the two is accidental.

Comment: Persian çun doesn't mean "when", I am a native Persian and Turkic speaker.
Also if we even accept it is old-Iranic, it still can be Turkic.

Comment: Turkic is not the mother of all languages, this is a fact that centuries before old-Turkic and old-Iranic Turks and Iranians were neighbors. I just fixed your wrong translation. çun means because, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Maybe *accidental* is not the right word, the could have become more similar in pronunciation or in sense because of confusion by speakers.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer. I doubt that very much. The two words have very different meanings and usages. Moreover, the Turkish word is already in Old Turkish, where it could have been influenced by Sogdian, but not by Persian.

Comment: "*different*" is a matter of subjectivity. Of course you might disagree with that and see it differently.

Comment: @fdb I was referring simply to the fact that the borrowing of Iranian *čūn* is pronounced *çün* in modern Turkish, whereas we might expect *çun* or *çûn*.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer. I understand your point. Classical Persian čūn is actually pronounced čun (čon) in modern Persian. This could have been borrowed into Azeri as çün.

Answer (score 1):

Turkish *çünki* comes from Persian *čūn* "because" and Persian *ke* "of". The literal meaning is "because of" and can be compared to French *parce-que*.

Turkish *için*, Azeri *üçün* and Uzbek *uchun* all come from Old Turkic *uç* "end, tip, boundary" + old Turkic suffix *+(I)n*. In modern turkish it means "for" and nothing else. *Ne için?* "for what?", *senin için* "for you". It **never** means "because of".

Your statement saying that there's no -un suffix in Turkish is completely false. 
+(I)n suffix produces time and place adverbs from nouns and adjectives in Old Turkic.  Most of the time + In, sometimes + An form is used.

Examples of words suffixed by +(I)n :
Yarın "tomorrow"
Erken "early"
Uzun "long"
Zorunlu "by force, obligated"
Ect. Ect.

In the case of için, the etymological meaning is "in the (location of the) limit, boundary, end of"

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I request two clarifications: a) I guess *čūn, ke* is supposed to reflect PIE \*kwo- (whence e.g. En *wh-words*, Lat *qu-*; please excuse the lack of superscript \*w) and \*ko-(m) (whence e.g. Lat *co-* etc, AGr *kei* "and"), is that on point? Translating literally *because of* is very biased by English (though note the *be-*, if akin to *by* which bears semantic resemblence to *of, with* etc, cp *whereby*; note too that labialized velars sometimes become plosives or delabialized, e.g. in Greek or Sanskrit respectively); b) please clarify "end, tip, boundary" > "for".

Comment: ... you probably imply "to what end" ("what for?"); cp Ger "endlich" ("finally, soon, now, ..."), "und nu" ("now what?"). Also note that *n-(e)-* was in Gothic, e.g., an inquisitive particle too. Funny that. *Oh* in Ancient Greek was similarly used as negation, while *-u-* was a preverbal pronoun often combined with *n-* in Gothic, cf V. V. Ivanov, Gothic Syntax, and others',; I don't know the half of it, it gives many questions to research; Such short particles are extremely difficult to derive, even synchronically, even less in young languages without a lot of early textual evidence. Oh no!